# does a primary clustered key default order ascending?

Tags: sql, database, azure-sql-database

I have a primary key as part of my table defined as follows:

```
PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED ([c_number], [property])
```

Does the database then keep the table sorted ascending by c_number by default?  Is it possible to put an `ASC` clarifier on the statement to ensure this?

This is deployed on a Microsoft Azure SQL database.

Comment: That's db specific. SQL is a query language, it doesn't maintain anything.

Comment: Sorry, you're right.  Terminology/understanding mixup

Comment: added it to the post now

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server, the data is stored in the data pages by the order of the clustered index, regardless of which index is defined as the primary key.

If you do not specify a sort order for the clustered index (or any index, for that matter), the order will be ascending, by default.

The main reason you should care is if you have a large number of range queries that are likely to be able to do sequential I/O if you cluster on a key relevant to those queries, as well as to combat/avoid fragmentation of your table.

The primary key does not have to be clustered, but you absolutely should define a clustered index for each table (else it is a heap table) in most situations, and, if your primary key is sequential in any meaningful way, it usually makes sense for your primary key to be the clustered key.

But again, based on the SQL you showed, the answer to your question is yes - the data will be stored in ascending order by the primary clustered key you have specified.  Depending on what that data is, you may be setting your table up for extreme fragmentation (composite clustered keys are rarely a good idea).

Your index is on `c_number, property`, which means that the index will be ordered by c_number ascending and then by property ascending, which means the data will also be stored that way.  As a data page fills up, if you were to perform inserts in the following order:

(1,1)
(1,2)
(2,1)
(1,3)

You would cause fragmentation, as the page will have to be split to insert the (1,3) value between (1,2) and (2,1).

I'd suggest that, unless that sort of situation can never happen or, unless your queries nearly always order, group, or filter on those two columns, that you cluster on a different column (not necessarily changing the columns of the primary key).

In any case, if you end up with a fragmented table, rebuild the clustered index during maintenance windows any time the fragmentation gets out of hand.  It'll greatly improve response time due to reduced random I/O.

Comment: I think I asked if the database keeps the table sorted in ascending order given how I specify my primary key.  Not whether the query will come back ordered.

Comment: It keeps the data sorted by the clustered index, regardless of what the primary key is.  Since you have declared your primary key to also be clustered, that is the way the data will be logically sorted within the data pages.